# In floating point computations, why truncated computations are slower than the precise computations?

Tags: java, precision

Cay Horstmann mentioned that the numerical community and the Java developers had a difference of opinion in implementing floating point computations, especially regarding Java portability across different architectures. But later Java developers were amenable to support extended precision for intermediate computations because truncated computations are slower than the precise computations. Why is it so? Sorry if the question is inane, I'm a novice in mathematics.

Comment: This has nothing to do with mathematics, it’s the number of instructions that need to be executed. On hardware that gives you extended computation “for free” you would need to issue an extra instruction to truncate the result, slowing down your computation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Java 8-byte double precision numbers map directly to the machine representation of floating point numbers in most modern CPUs. 4-byte floats, on the other hand, have to be converted back and forth to 8-byte form.

About the only thing 4-byte floats are useful for now is saving space when you have a lot of floating point data and saving space is more important than precision or speed.

Comment: I don't think that's what they're talking about; I think this is about [x86 80-bit floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format).